# How to get a Stream of download url in firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

i want to create  a stream of firebase storage download link for all the images

```
   firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
       firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
   firebase_storage.Reference ref =
       storage.ref().child('images');
   firebase_storage.ListResult result = await ref.listAll();
   result.items.forEach((firebase_storage.Reference ref) async* {
     print('Found file: $ref');
     yield (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
   });
 }
```

the snapshot data is null
if i create with future it seems to work when i add all the urls in a list  and give to listview builder
but i cant get each string through stream

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with ForEach and await getDownloadUrl().  Try using a for loop instead.

```
 for (Reference refin result.items) async* {
  print('Found file: $ref');
  yield (await getDownloadUrl().toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing first create a instance of FirebaseStorage**

```dart
final _firestorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
```

**after then we need ref. for get image from storage.**

```dart
final ref = _firestorage.ref().child('image');
```

**and then we can create image's url.**

```dart
var imageURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

**and try this.**

```dart
print(imageURL);
```

*if you wanna get this codes into fully method:*

```dart
String getImageURL(){
  final _firestorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final ref = _firestorage.ref().child('image');
  var imageURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  if(imageURL != null){
    return imageURL;
  }else{
    print("Couldn't load image");
  }
}
```

Also you can get this image with `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder` etc. for get more about FirebaseStorage check it out this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage)